# How to Make Black Weapons?

Tags: borderlands-2

How do you make a black weapon in Borderlands 2? Have they patched it or is it very difficult to do?

I have no clue how to make them.

Comment: Do you have a weapon name? Or a screenshot to show what you mean? I have no idea what weapons you're talking about.

Comment: Neither do i. I've seen pretty much everything in this game, but I've never seen a black weapon. There are some YouTube vids though, but i think they are either fake or the weapons are added with a mod.

Comment: [Here](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=189760) is some useful information on Black Rarity

Comment: @Batophobia - do you need to sign up to that website to see the thread?  Page doesn't appear for me.

Comment: @rasteve The page has since been deleted.  Good example of why you should always summarize links in your answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Black rarity is apparently a hack that was [supposedly patched a very long time ago](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/638784-borderlands-2/67105305). It was never an intended part of the game though, played over 300 hours since launch. They're not drops.

Comment: I know there not drops I was asking how to make them or if there patched, well you still answered my question

Answer (score 0):

You use a gibbed save editor and you put different parts of guns into 1 gun the out come is black rarity weapons (hybrid)

Answer (score -1):

Black weapons are hybrids that are always overpowered.

Some can carry 999+ ammunition, some do not even use ammunition. Some can do 1,000,000,000,000,000 damage, and some can fire much faster then their average counterparts.

You can use a save editor to edit the items into your game.

Answer (score -3):

Black weapons are very real, and are a blast to use/make. They are made by using a gamesave editor to pull pieces from whatever weapons you want to make a new one. Barrels are what have the special effects on almost all guns so a lot black weapons were made out of almost nothing but barrels.

An example would be a rapidfire shotgun with a bottomless clip and each pellet is a mini nuke, or an alien sniper that fires as fast as the Shredifier, or a rapidfire Norfleet that fires 9 orbs instead of 3, etc.

As this was patched a long time ago, there is a group who has come up with a workaround using CheatEngine to inject a script that disables the scan the game does for black weapons when launched. Hopefully they will find a more convenient method as time goes on, but this works for now.